# jQuery + AJAX to retrieve data sent by an input submit type

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am wanting to use the AJAX function via jQuery to return some data onto my homepage. Currently, I am using an 'action=' on my form to an external PHP file just to check that the data is being sent and it is. I'm now wanting to use AJAX to return this data into a div on my homepage. I have this code but at the moment it's not returning any data:

```
$("#ticketSearch").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    var eNameData = ("#postcodeSearch").val();
      alert('#ticketSearch clicked'); //this alert doesn't even work!

    var dataToSend = 'postcodeSearch=' + eNameData;

    $.ajax({                
        url: "index.php", 
        type: "POST",
        data: dataToSend,     
        cache: false,
        success: function(php_output)
            {
            $("#ticketResults").html(php_output).show();
            }
    }); 
});
```

The code for the form:

```
<form name="pcSearchForm" id="pcSearchForm" class="pcSearchForm"  method="post" action="postCodeSearch.php"> // the action method needs to be taken out

        <input type="text" name="postcodeSearch" id="postcodeSearch" class="postcodeSearch" placeholder="Postcode..." /> 

        <input type="submit" name="ticketSearch" id="ticketSearch" class="ticketSearch" value="Search" /> 

</form>
```

Any help is much appreciated, I think I am on the right lines but something just isn't right!
Thank you.

EDIT: New code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ticketSearch").click(function(e) {
alert("click");
e.preventDefault();
var eNameData = $("#postcodeSearch").val();
 alert('eNameData');
 });

var dataToSend = 'postcodeSearch=' + eNameData;

    $.ajax({                
        url: "index.php", 
        type: "POST",
        data: dataToSend,     
        cache: false,
        success: function(php_output)
            {
            $("#ticketResults").html(php_output);
            alert("#ticketResults");
            }
    }); 
});
```

The form:

```
        <input type="text" name="postcodeSearch" id="postcodeSearch" class="postcodeSearch" placeholder="Postcode..." /> 

        <input type="button" name="ticketSearch" id="ticketSearch" class="ticketSearch" value="Search" />


    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong dude :) ..

Change

```
var eNameData = ("#postcodeSearch").val();
```

to

```
var eNameData = $("#postcodeSearch").val();
```

I wonder why you use `alert('#ticketSearch clicked');` .

What's its use. If you need to alert the data postcodeSearch,

then just do

```
 alert(eNameData');
```

Hope this helps you :)

**EDIT:**

Your code seems to be wrong, Your click event is closed before the ajax call is done. Also i think you are calling the wrong file. Your form submit action page is **postCodeSearch.php** but in ajax you are calling `index.php`

Your code should be changed to :

**FORM :**

```
<form name="pcSearchForm" id="pcSearchForm" class="pcSearchForm"  method="post" action="postCodeSearch.php"> // the action method needs to be taken out

        <input type="text" name="postcodeSearch" id="postcodeSearch" class="postcodeSearch" placeholder="Postcode..." /> 

        <input type="button" name="ticketSearch" id="ticketSearch" class="ticketSearch" value="Search" /> 

</form>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ticketSearch").click(function(e) {
       var eNameData = $("#postcodeSearch").val();
       var dataToSend = 'postcodeSearch=' + eNameData;

       $.ajax({                
           url: "postCodeSearch.php", 
           type: "POST",
           data: dataToSend,     
           cache: false,
           success: function(php_output) {
               $("#ticketResults").html(php_output);
           }
       }); 
    }); 
});
```

Hope this helps you. :)

Comment: Can you try debugging the ajax call in firebug

Comment: go to the net panel in firebug. Check if any errors are there in console

Comment: can you try alerting the output. I doubt if the ajax call is returning empty output. Is their any url i can check with ??

Comment: Hey can you do one thing. In your form can you change type="submit" to type="button" and try. Since type="submit" actually submits the form without listening to the javascript click function.

Comment: Yeah. That was the problem. You should change type="submit" to type="button" in your form. Then only click event can be listened. Sorry din't notice it earlier

Comment: Thank you for the trouble :) ...I've used Net on Firebug and it's showing there's a response has occurred and corresponds to the search, however it's not being outputted on the homepage. This must be down to the php I've written?

Comment: I've managed to output the code...however I have just one question. When I enter a search query, the Ajax does bring back the result but with less data than is expected. I type in NE1, it will bring back all the results yet when I enter B1 it brings back 2 less results, does this have anything to do with the .val() method?

Answer (score 1):

Error: "#postcodeSearch".val is not a function

Use:

```
var eNameData = $("#postcodeSearch").val();
```

instead of:

```
var eNameData = ("#postcodeSearch").val();
```

Comment: @EvilP No it's not. The `$` references jQuery. Please read more careful.

Comment: oh sorry, didn't read that carefully, did focus on the val ^.^ sorry dude

Answer (score 1):

open firebug / chrome dev tools and in your success function put

console.log(php_output)

Answer (score 0):

```
var eNameData = $("#postcodeSearch").val();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fgtzd/

Comment: @Rizwan Mumtaz: Thank you for your response, the link in particular is a cool site never stumbled upon before!